# Strange Result from FFT using Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I'm trying to do an FFT of some data (a Gaussian pulse), but I'm finding a strange result. The real and imaginary components of the resultant FFT alternate in sign every index of the array. The absolute values of the arrays, however, are continuous. So, I get something that looks like this:

[image: FFT of Gaussian pulse]

Does anybody have an idea on what is causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Linking this more or less same question here: [Strange phase for gaussian beam 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556913/strange-phase-for-gaussian-beam-2d)

Answer (score 6):

Alternating signs in the frequency domain corresponds to an `exp(j*pi*n)` complex factor which by the [shift theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Shift_theorem) corresponds to a time domain circular shift of `N/2` samples. Looking at your time domain Gaussian pulse you should notice that the peak indeed appears at `N/2` instead of index 0.

Shifting back your time domain Gaussian pulse with [`ifftshift`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.ifftshift.html) should give you a pulse centered at 0 whose frequency domain representation does not have this sign alternation.

Comment: You should use `iffshift` not `fftshift` (I know, confusing nomenclature)