# Strange phase for gaussian beam 2D

Tags: python, fft

I have Gaussian beam in 2D:

[image: 2D Gaussian]

After doing `fft2` and angle I get strange results:

[image: magnitude of FFT]

[image: phase of FFT]

```
def finite2D(x,y, N, M, a, hx):
    f = np.array([[0.0]*N]*N)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for k in range(len(y)):
            f[i][k] = np.exp(-(x[i]*x[i] + y[k]*y[k]))

    D1 = fftpack.fft2(f)
    D2 = fftpack.fftshift(D1)

    b = N*N/(4*a*M)
    x = np.linspace(-b, b, N)
    y = np.linspace(-b, b, N)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    plt.imshow(np.abs(D2))
    plt.show()

    plt.imshow(np.angle(D2))
    plt.show(True)
    return D2, phas

a = 5
N = 128
M = 256
b = N*N/(4*a*M)
hx = 2*a/N
x = np.linspace(-a, a, N)
y = np.linspace(-a, a, N)
finite2D(x,y, N, M, a, hx)
```

It should be phase 0 or close to 0. Why is this not the case, and how do I fix this?

///Updated:

```
def finite2D(x,y, N, M, a, hx):
    f = np.array([[0.0]*N]*N)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for k in range(len(y)):
            f[i][k] = np.exp(-(x[i]*x[i] + y[k]*y[k]))

    f = fftpack.ifftshift(f)
    D1 = fftpack.fft2(f)
    D2 = fftpack.fftshift(D1)

    b = N*N/(4*a*M)
    x = np.linspace(-b, b, N)
    y = np.linspace(-b, b, N)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    plt.imshow(np.abs(D2))
    plt.show()

    plt.imshow(np.angle(D2))
    plt.show(True)
    return D2

a = 5
N = 128
M = 256
b = N*N/(4*a*M)
hx = 2*a/N
x = np.linspace(-a, a, N, endpoint=False)
y = np.linspace(-a, a, N, endpoint=False)
finite2D(x,y, N, M, a, hx)
```

Phase:
[image: Phase]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Analytical Fourier transform vs FFT of functions in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317834/analytical-fourier-transform-vs-fft-of-functions-in-matlab)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I do not quite understand how this can solve my problem.
Could you help me fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FFT asumes that the origin is in the top-left corner of the image. Thus, you are computing the FFT of a Gaussian shifted by half the image size. This shift leads to a high-frequency phase shift in the frequency domain.

To solve the problem, you need to shift the origin of your Gaussian signal to the top-left corner of the image. `ifftshift` does this:

```
f = fftpack.ifftshift(f)
D1 = fftpack.fft2(f)
D2 = fftpack.fftshift(D1)
```

---

Note that where the magnitude is very small, the phase is defined by rounding errors, don’t expect zero phase there.

---

The updated result looks good, but there still is a very small gradient in the central region. This is caused by the half-pixel shift of the Gaussian. This shift is given by the definition of the `x` and `y` coordinates:

```
N = 128
x = np.linspace(-a, a, N)
y = np.linspace(-a, a, N)
```

For an even-sized `N`, do

```
x = np.linspace(-a, a, N, endpoint=False)
y = np.linspace(-a, a, N, endpoint=False)
```

such that there is a sample where `x==0`.

Comment: @SoH: Please check updated answer. I didn’t pay attention to details after finding the big obvious issue. :)

Comment: @SoH: Sorry for not being explicit, both the `x` and the `y` need the same treatment. Notice how your change of `x` removed one of the gradients. Changing `y` in the same way will remove the other gradient.